# Problems targeting the correct div id with dynamically (javascript) created divs

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I'm having troubles targeting the correct div id with dynamically (javascript) created divs.

How it should function..

1. Each time you press the add text button a new text input is created with an incrementing id
2. When you type into this box the text appears in the results div
3. The same will repeat each time you press the add text button.

So far all of the above functions as I would expect.

The problem..
When you add a second text then try to edit the first text the id is wrong so the first text does not update.

How can I make this function as expected so no matter how many texts you add you can edit a previous one and it updates the correct id?

```js
let textcount = 0;

function addtext() {
  textcount++
  
  //create textarea with incrimenting id
  var newtext = document.createElement("div");
  newtext.id = "text" + (textcount);
  newtext.innerHTML = "text id = " + (textcount) + "<br><textarea placeholder=\"Start Typing\" id=\"textarea" + textcount + "\" class=\"textarea\" oninput=\"updatetext();\" autocomplete=\"off\" ></textarea>";
  document.getElementById("newtextboxappend").appendChild(newtext);
  
  
//create results div with matching id
 var shownewtext = document.createElement("div");
  shownewtext.id = "showtext" + (textcount);
  document.getElementById("resultsappend").appendChild(shownewtext);
  document.getElementById("showtext" + (textcount)).innerText = document.getElementById("textarea" + (textcount)).value; 

}

function updatetext() {
  document.getElementById("showtext" + (textcount)).innerText = (textcount) + ") " + document.getElementById("textarea" + (textcount)).value;
    //console log id when typing to see what id is being targeted
  console.log(textcount);
};
```

```css
.newtextboxescontain {
 width:100%;
 border: 1px black solid;
 }
 
 .resultscontain {
 width: 100%;
 border: 0.5px black solid;
 }
 
 textarea {
   width: 95%;
   height: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="addtext();">Add Text</button>
<br /><br />
Text Inputs: <br />
<div id="newtextboxescontain" class="newtextboxescontain">
<div id="newtextboxappend"></div>
</div>
<br />

Results: <br />
<div id="resultscontain" class="resultscontain">

<div id="resultsappend"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use numbered ids. Wrap the text and input in a div and go up to it, then down to find the text. Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/ck8uzqp9/ (this also uses event delegation for the `input` event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you was getting the id to use, you was getting the number of the index. Like length. You was getting the last number. I changed a little and it worked, see below:

```js
let textcount = 0;

function addtext() {
  textcount++
  
  //create textarea with incrimenting id
  var newtext = document.createElement("div");
  newtext.id = "text" + (textcount);
  newtext.innerHTML = "text id = " + (textcount) + "<br><textarea placeholder=\"Start Typing\" id=\"textarea" + textcount + "\" class=\"textarea\" oninput=\"updatetext(event);\" autocomplete=\"off\" ></textarea>";
  document.getElementById("newtextboxappend").appendChild(newtext);
  
  
//create results div with matching id
 var shownewtext = document.createElement("div");
  shownewtext.id = "showtext" + (textcount);
  document.getElementById("resultsappend").appendChild(shownewtext);
  document.getElementById("showtext" + (textcount)).innerText = document.getElementById("textarea" + (textcount)).value; 

}

function updatetext(e) {
  var ideditaded = e.target.getAttribute("id").replace("textarea", ""); // get the id of what you are editing and remove the textarea to get only its textcount.
  document.getElementById("showtext" + (ideditaded)).innerText = (ideditaded) + ") " + document.getElementById("textarea" + (ideditaded)).value;
    //console log id when typing to see what id is being targeted
  //console.log(ideditaded);
};
```

```css
.newtextboxescontain {
 width:100%;
 border: 1px black solid;
 }
 
 .resultscontain {
 width: 100%;
 border: 0.5px black solid;
 }
 
 textarea {
   width: 95%;
   height: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="addtext();">Add Text</button>
<br /><br />
Text Inputs: <br />
<div id="newtextboxescontain" class="newtextboxescontain">
<div id="newtextboxappend"></div>
</div>
<br />

Results: <br />
<div id="resultscontain" class="resultscontain">

<div id="resultsappend"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, a great help and i have managed to apply the same logic to all of my other elements in the same manor but one of them if differant and i'm stuck apply the same logic to the last one (font picker).  please have a look at this paste bin and see if you could help.. https://pastebin.com/N6rJSqYp

Comment: I have now asked a new question on here for this new problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401626/sending-id-via-javascript-listener