# Sending id via javascript listener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For all my other options this works great (i just editing the replace part to be the correct id)..

(Note: all "'s are 'd out as in production these are dynamically created with js)

```
<div class=\"singlecontrol\"><span style=\"vertical-align: middle;\">Colour Picker</span><input oninput=\"updatetxtcolour(event)\" id=\"colourpicker"+textcount+"\" value=\"#dfe481\" type=\"color\" autocomplete=\"off\" ></div>
 
<script> 
function updatetxtcolour(e) {
    var ideditaded = e.target.getAttribute("id").replace("colourpicker", "");
document.getElementById("quotetext"+(ideditaded)).style.color = document.getElementById("colourpicker"+(ideditaded)).value;
}
 </script>
```

But for my font picker it works like so...

```
<div class=\"singlecontrol\"><span style=\"vertical-align: middle;\">Font Picker</span><input id=\"font"+textcount+"\" type=\"text\" autocomplete=\"off\" ></div>
 
 
<script> 
$('#font'+(textcount))
                .fontselect()
                .on('change', function() {
                applyFont(this.value);
                });
 
        } 
 
  
    function applyFont(font) {
      console.log('You selected font: ' + font);
     
      // Replace + signs with spaces for css
      font = font.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
     
      // Split font into family and weight
      font = font.split(':');
     
      var fontFamily = font[0];
      var fontWeight = font[1] || 400;
     
      // Set selected font on paragraphs
      $('quotetext'+(textcount)).css({fontFamily:"'"+fontFamily+"'", fontWeight:fontWeight});
 
}
</script>
```

I'm having trouble getting the latter font picker to function in the same manner as the others, that is to pass the correct ID as these are created dynamically like so https://stackoverflow.com/a/69397361/4772471

All of my other options call a function oninput but this one uses a listener and then runs a function so i'm stumpted.

Comment: Please do not invalidate valid answers by incorporating them into your question via editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (you must use the '#' sign):

```
$('#quotetext'+(textcount)).css({fontFamily:"'"+fontFamily+"'", fontWeight:fontWeight});
```

Instead of:

```
$('quotetext'+(textcount)).css({fontFamily:"'"+fontFamily+"'", fontWeight:fontWeight});
```

In addition, you can use template string (learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), will be much more readable:

```
$(`#quotetext${textcount}`)
```

Comment: Thank you for that, noted and changed, my main probem is trying to pass the id the same as the others using  ('ideditaded' ) rather than the ('textcount')  so as to pass the correct id when many are being used.

Comment: So you want the id to be passed from the colour picker?

Comment: no, I want the id from the font picker to be passed in the same way as the colour picker is, reason being, they are dymanically created and using textcount passes the wrong id, You can test it out and see what I mean here https://dev.mockupmonkey.co.uk/postermaker/ Add 2 lots of text then try and change the font on the first. wont work, but if you cange anything else on the first it will work as expected.

Comment: If it helps this is where I had the 'font picker' from https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/system-google-font-picker.html

Comment: I will look for that after work ;)